# 2 divs left , and one individual

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a layout 2 divs in the left , and one indivudal to the right , but however I am getting 3 divs in vertical . I am currently using bootstrap 3.3.7 , how can I achieve this?
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgR1A.png)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-md-block">
    <div class="col-9 border float-left" style="background-color: red">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 border taller float-right" style="background-color: blue">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 border" style="background-color: green">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make two columns of `col-6` class. This would split the screen into two columns. Next, in the first column, add a `row`, and in that row, add two `col-12` columns. This would make the columns look like what you want.
Use this code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                1 of 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                3 of 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="col-12" style="margin-left: -1rem">
        2 of 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem in the question, so that it is useful for other users also.